# Why isn't AUTOINCREMENT null on SQLITE? | Autoincrement ID in sqlite flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, sqflite

I added this one on onCreate method on SQFLITE. I need to generate an autoincrement id. I printed id but the value is null. How to add autoincrement id using sqflite?

```
   await db.execute(
            """CREATE TABLE submitRequestTable(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,equipmentId INTEGER, woDescriptionId INTEGER, details STRING, priorityId INTEGER,
            workTypeId INTEGER, sourceId INTEGER, filename STRING, isOffline INTEGER, systemDate STRING, username STRING, subItemId INTEGER, status STRING)""");
      }
```

I store data like this. I didn't add id to value. i didn't pass to value to id.

```
  storeSubmitRequest(
      BuildContext context,
      int equipmentId,
      int woDescriptionId,
      String details,
      int priorityId,
      int workTypeId,
      int sourceId,
      String filename,
      int isOffline,
      String systemDate,
      String username,
      int subItemId,
      String status) async {
    var db = await db1;
    Batch batch = db.batch();
    var data = SubmitRequestModel(
        equipmentId: equipmentId,
        woDescriptionId: woDescriptionId,
        details: details,
        priorityId: priorityId,
        workTypeId: workTypeId,
        sourceId: sourceId,
        filename: filename,
        isOffline: isOffline,
        systemDate: systemDate,
        username: username,
        subItemId: subItemId,
        status: status);
    batch.insert(
      'submitRequestTable',
      data.toJson(),
      // conflictAlgorithm: ConflictAlgorithm.replace,
    );
    await batch.commit();
    Navigator.push(
        context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ListPage("")));
  }
```

Comment: How about other fields?

Comment: @PhucTran I edited my question

Comment: @pskink I edited my question

Comment: id is null. i guess i didnt add any thing to id.

Comment: is it need to add null value to id when insert data to table?

Answer (score 5):

You need to make sure that the id is not added to the map in your `toJson()` function:

In the official documentation it is handled like this:

```
Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
  var map = <String, dynamic>{
    columnTitle: title,
    columnDone: done == true ? 1 : 0
  };

  if (id != null) map['id'] = id;

  return map;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need remove null value from **Map**, for example:

```dart
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final map = {
      "id": this.id,
      "type": this.type.value,
      "count": this.count,
      "currency": this.currency,
      "category": this.category,
      "comment": this.comment,
      "timestamp": this.timestamp
    };

    map.removeWhere((key, value) => value == null);

    return map;
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

Add this line to initialize **DB** with `autoincrement` id

```
id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT
```

**Example code**

```
'CREATE TABLE dogs(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NUL, name TEXT, age INTEGER)'
```

**Full code with example**

```
import 'package:path/path.dart';
    import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';
    
    import '../modal/dogs_model.dart';
    
        class DataBaseHelper {
          Future<Database> initializedDB() async {
            return openDatabase(
              // Set the path to the database. Note: Using the `join` function from the
              // `path` package is best practice to ensure the path is correctly
              // constructed for each platform.
              join(await getDatabasesPath(), 'doggie_database.db'),
              // When the database is first created, create a table to store dogs.
              onCreate: (db, version) {
                // Run the CREATE TABLE statement on the database.
                return db.execute(
                  'CREATE TABLE dogs(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NUL, name TEXT, age INTEGER)',
                );
              },
              // Set the version. This executes the onCreate function and provides a
              // path to perform database upgrades and downgrades.
              version: 1,
            );
          }
          Future<void> insertDog(Dog dog) async {
            // Get a reference to the database.
            final db = await initializedDB();
        
            // Insert the Dog into the correct table. You might also specify the
            // `conflictAlgorithm` to use in case the same dog is inserted twice.
            //
            // In this case, replace any previous data.
            await db.insert(
              'dogs',
              dog.toMap(),
              conflictAlgorithm: ConflictAlgorithm.replace,
            );
          }
          // A method that retrieves all the dogs from the dogs table.
          Future<List<Dog>> dogs() async {
            // Get a reference to the database.
            final db = await initializedDB();
        
            // Query the table for all The Dogs.
            final List<Map<String, dynamic>> maps = await db.query('dogs');
        
            // Convert the List<Map<String, dynamic> into a List<Dog>.
            return List.generate(maps.length, (i) {
              return Dog(
                id: maps[i]['id'],
                name: maps[i]['name'],
                age: maps[i]['age'],
              );
            });
          }
        }
```

**Dog Model**

```
class Dog {
          final int id;
          final String name;
          final int age;
        
          const Dog({
            required this.id,
            required this.name,
            required this.age,
          });
        
          // Convert a Dog into a Map. The keys must correspond to the names of the
          // columns in the database.
          Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
            return {
              'name': name,
              'age': age,
            };
          }
        
          // Implement toString to make it easier to see information about
          // each dog when using the print statement.
          @override
          String toString() {
            return 'Dog{id: $id, name: $name, age: $age}';
          }
        }
```

**Usage in stateful class**

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
      final TextEditingController nameTextEditingController =
          TextEditingController();
      final TextEditingController ageTextEditingController =
          TextEditingController();
      List<Dog> dogsList = [];
      late DataBaseHelper dataBaseHelper;
      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        dataBaseHelper=DataBaseHelper();
        dataBaseHelper.initializedDB().whenComplete(() { getList();});
      }
    
      getList() async {
        dogsList = await DataBaseHelper().dogs();
        setState(() {
    
        });
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            // TRY THIS: Try changing the color here to a specific color (to
            // Colors.amber, perhaps?) and trigger a hot reload to see the AppBar
            // change color while the other colors stay the same.
            backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary,
            // Here we take the value from the MyHomePage object that was created by
            // the App.build method, and use it to set our appbar title.
            title: Text(widget.title),
          ),
          body: dogsList != null && dogsList.length > 0
              ? ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: dogsList.length,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    return ListTile(
                        leading: const Icon(Icons.list),
                        title: Text(dogsList[index].name));
                  })
              : Center(
                  child: Text('No data found'),
                ),
          floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: () {
              _displayTextInputDialog(context);
            },
            tooltip: 'Increment',
            child: const Icon(Icons.add),
          ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
        );
      }
    
      Future<void> _displayTextInputDialog(BuildContext context) async {
        return showDialog(
            context: context,
            builder: (context) {
              return AlertDialog(
                title: Text('TextField in Dialog'),
                content: Column(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  children: [
                    TextField(
                      onChanged: (value) {
                        setState(() {});
                      },
                      controller: nameTextEditingController,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: "Dog name"),
                    ),
                    TextField(
                      onChanged: (value) {
                        setState(() {});
                      },
                      controller: ageTextEditingController,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: "Dog age"),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                actions: <Widget>[
                  MaterialButton(
                    color: Colors.green,
                    textColor: Colors.white,
                    child: Text('Add'),
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() async {
                        Navigator.pop(context);
                        // Create a Dog and add it to the dogs table
                        var dog = Dog(
                          id: 0,
                          name: nameTextEditingController.value.text,
                          age: int.parse(ageTextEditingController.value.text),
                        );
                       await DataBaseHelper().insertDog(dog);
                        getList();
                      });
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              );
            });
      }
    }
```